# Python for loop with a more intuitive upper bound?

Tags: python, for-loop

Sometimes it is a little confusing for me to keep in mind that the upperbound for a for loop is excluded by default. Is there any way to make it inclusive?

Comment: Although you describe it as "more intuitive", you will find that in the majority of coding situations, upper bounds are exclusive (for similar reasons that indexing traditionally starts at 0 rather than 1).  So I would suggest not getting into the habit of doing something non-standard...

Comment: Python's `for in` loop abstracts lower and upper bounds, what loop construct are you using?

Comment: oh well then just do `for i in range(x, upper + 1)`, but as @OliCharlesworth mentions the upper bound is exclusive in most cases because indexing of arrays and lists starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: I've found the easiest way to remember it: the index of the first item you want, followed by the index of the first item you *don't* want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `for i in range(upper + 1)` or if you like, `for i in range(lower, upper + 1)` will work,

A lot of programming languages use zero-based indexing, so the non-inclusive upper bound is a common practice (this is due to memory addressing and adding an offset)

Just an example: If you had an array of size 5, `ar`, starting with index **0**, *your largest valid index* value would be **4** (i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), but your loop construct would refer to the size of the array (5) like so:

`for i in range(5):`

or more common and better:

`for i in range(len(ar)):`

.. ensuring you only get legal index values 0 .. 4.

Comment: My misunderstanding then, thanks! I think I am just used to C++ where I can do for-loops with less-than-or-equal-to conditions.

Comment: @user1435323 But even in C++ you almost never do that for the same reasons. And as soon as you write recursive algorithms you'll notice that splitting an input into two equal sized parts is much easier with exclusive bounds too. So it's a really good idea to design your APIs correspondingly.

Comment: Your example is a bad one - you should never be looping over the indices of a sequence in Python. If you need to iterate for each item in the sequence, but not use it, throw away (`for _ in seq:`), if you need the indexes use `enumerate()` (`for i, value in enumerate(seq)`), if you want to iterate over multiple sequences at once use `zip()` (`for value_a, value_b in zip(seq_a, seq_b):`) and if you just want to iterate, iterate (`for value in seq:`). The only time you should iterate over a `range()` is when you literally just want to iterate over numbers.

Answer (score 11):

Nine times out of ten, if you are writing a Python `for` loop that iterates through a range of numbers and then use those numbers to index into a list or other container, you're doing it wrong.  In other words, instead of doing this:

```
for i in range(len(container)):
    print container[i]
```

You should be doing this:

```
for item in container:
    print item
```

But wait! you object. What if I need the index because I'm going to modify the items in some way?  The Pythonic way to do this is with the `enumerate()` built-in function.

```
for i, item in enumerate(container):
    print item
    container[i] += 1
```

If you don't mind making a copy of your list, then the list comprehension often is the best choice:

```
container = [item + 1 for item in container]
```

Or if you need to modify the list in place, try this, which combines a slice assignment (to replace the existing list) and a generator expression (to lazily modify the items):

```
 container[:] = (item + 1 for item in container)
```

Comment: This should be at the top, honestly. My first thought when I saw the OP's question was 'what is this, `for` loops don't skip an upper bound, and in fact "bound" isn't even a meaningful concept here; the loop iterates over a collection of elements, executing once with each element'.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get used to it. Just add one to the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

You could define one without too much pain:

```
def fullrange(lower, upper, step = 1):
    return range(lower, upper + 1, step)
```

But as others have said, it may just be better to get used to`range(lower, upper + 1)`.  I'd say the intentions with the `+ 1` are pretty clear.